# Solutions of $(x\cdot y) > x+y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many pairs would exist in a given set of numbers such that $(x\cdot y) > x+y$ and $x,y\geq0$

My solution
If $x$ or $y$ is $0$ or $1$ then the pair cannot hold true for the given condition. so all pairs of numbers $> 1$ would be the solution.

Am I correct?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $x$ and $y$? Non-negative? Integers?

Comment: x,y>=0. Sorry i forgot the =

Comment: They are integers too.

Comment: This holds for all $x,y\geqslant2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You might want to sketch the curve $xy=x+y$, i.e. $y=\dfrac{x}{x-1}$ or $y=1+\dfrac{1}{x-1}$

[image]

***Added:*** since your question is apparently restricted to non-negative integers, you want those integer pairs of coordinates strictly above the upper-right red line (or strictly below the lower left red line).

You are correct that this excludes cases where $x$ or $y$ are $0$ or $1$.  But there is another case it excludes if you want $xy \gt x+y$ to be strictly true.  Try adding integer coordinate pairs to the sketch.

Comment: I don't get it :(

Comment: I can't figure out the other case. The graph will continue to expand such that all integer pairs where x,y>1 will come into that space, won't it?

Comment: GOT IT! 2*2 and 2+2 right?

Comment: An aside: $xy>x+y \iff xy-x-y+1 > 1 \iff (x-1)(y-1)>1$.  This may give you a more algebraic way to solve the inequality (and you can immediately see that it is false for $x=2,y=2$.)